# SQL to set a value based on a value from a diffrent table automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title may not be that helpful but what I am trying to do is this.

For simplicity's sake I have two tables one called logs and another called Log controls

In LOGS I have and a log event column, this is automatically populated by imported information. On the LOG CONTROLS I have a manually entered list of Log events (to match the ones coming in) and I have this table to have them assigned ID numbers and other details about the event.

What I need to do is have a column in the `LOGS` table which looks at the Log events, matches it to the ID from the LOG CONTROLS table and assigns the ID into the `LOGS` table.

I have seen a few methods of changing information in columns based of information in other tables but all of these seem to be one way checks i.e if `ID = X` change to VALUE FROM OTHER TABLE where as what I need is `IF VALUE = X FROM OTHER TABLE CHANGE ID FIELD TO = Y` FROM OTHER TABLE

Below is a mock up of the tables.

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+  
| ID | Date_Time |  Event    | Control ID|  
+----+-----------+----------+------------+  
|  1 | 0/0/0     | Shutdown |            |  
|  2 | 0/0/0     | Start up |            |  
|  3 | 0/0/0     | Error    |            |  
|  4 | 0/0/0     | Info     |            |  
| 5  | 0/0/0     | Shutdown |            |  
| 6  | 0/0/0     | Error    |            |  
+----+-----------+----------+------------+  

+-------------------+----------+--------+-------+   
| Control ID        | Event    | Export | Flag  |
+-------------------+----------+--------+-------+  
| 1                 | Shutdown | TRUE   | TRUE  |  
| 2                 | Start up | TRUE   | FALSE |  
| 3                 | Error    | TRUE   | TRUE  |  
| 4                 | Info     | TRUE   | FALSE |  
+-------------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

So I need the Control ID in the first table to match the control ID from the second table depending on what the event was.

I hope this makes sense.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. What would really help is some table definition, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it seems that a simple `UPDATE` statement is all you need:

```
update logs
set control_id = c.control_id
from log_controls as c
where c.event = logs.event;
```

Comment: Yeah that does it! I think I was over complicating it a bit. Thanks for the help :)